# Simultaneous execution of "rsync" into same destination

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to know if the simultaneous execution of "rsync" into the same destination cause a problem.

I am now preparing following commands and it is a situation.

1. a following command is executed asynchronously. 
   rsync -acv --delete --progress --stats --exclude='*tmp*' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/"  /home/yuki/*.tar.gz /home/yuki/dist/
2. while executing the No.1 rsync command, a program do other tasks.
3. then No.2 tasks are completed, then the program implements the following command without waiting for the No.1 command.
   rsync -acv --delete --progress --stats --exclude='*tmp*' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/"  /home/yuki/*.END /home/yuki/dist/

when the No.1 and the No.3 steps are executed simultaneously on Linux, Are these executed properly? or result in any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your file names do not overlap: `*.tar.gz` and `*.END`.  Due to the concurrent file creation, the directory listing operating on the target could give strange results, but I think rsync will deal with any duplicated or missing file names in this particular case.

The `--delete` worries me a bit, but it should be ignored anyway because I assume you are not transferring any directories.